# Robot framework: How to Log out from web application and close chrome browser using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

My Robot framework Execution hangs after clicking on log out.

Here is my sample Code:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    //a[contains(text(),'Log Out')]
Click Link    //a[contains(text(),'Log Out')]
Close Browser 
Open Webpage    ${browser}    ${user}    &{Login}[${user}]    ${Url_Link}
Maximize Browser Window
```

This Code works on Firefox, But with Google Chrome the execution is Hanging at the Below step.

```
Click Link    //a[contains(text(),'Log Out')]
```

Clicking on the Logout is successful, But the execution Hangs in the same step and it doesn't go the next step. However this works fine with Firefox.

Request to help me with any suggestions.

Comment: did you tried providing sleep before click and also try with javascript click once

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs" - nothing happens, e.g. the user is not logged out, and the browser is not closed, or the chrome system process becomes unresponsive?

Comment: User is getting Logged out. Problem is with chrome Browser, Browser is not getting closed after logging out and test execution is struck there itself.

Comment: More Information:
Output:

    20180803 18:21:10.779 : INFO : Clicking link '//a[contains(text(),'Log Out')]'.

Even after application logged out it still waits at the same step and doesn't move further.

Comment: Have you tried : "Close Window" ?

Comment: Yes @YOBA. I tried but see the same issue.

Comment: OK I have no clue, I had some issues with Chrome as well, try updating your Chrome version to the latest !